# Finite number of negative elements in a sequence converging to infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

There is a sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3 ...$ of real numbers $\{a_n\}\in\mathbb{R}$ that diverges to plus infinity. At least the first element is negative $a_1<0$. Is it possible to prove that only a finite number of numbers $\{a_n\}$ are negative? Is the condition $a_1\leq a_2\leq a_3\leq ...$ necessary for the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\forall x\in \mathbb R \;\exists m_x\in \mathbb N \;\forall n>m_x\;(a_n>x)\implies$$ $$\implies \exists m_0\in \mathbb N\;\forall n>m_0\;(a_n>0)\implies$$ $$\implies \exists m_0\in \mathbb N\;\forall n\;(a_n\leq 0\implies n\leq m_0)\implies$$ $$\implies \exists m_0\in \mathbb N\;(\{n\in \mathbb N:a_n\leq 0\}\subset \{1,...,m_0\}).$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes , by definition, if the sequence converges to positive infinity, there is for every real number $R$ a time $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $a_n \geq R$ for all later n and as you observe you don't have to use monotonicity of your sequence

Comment: It is important  to specify: ''for every real number $R>0$''. And I don't love the expression ''converge to positive infinite''. Better:''diverge to $+\infty$''.

Comment: It's not clear which of his questions your "Yes" goes for.

Comment: No, "every real number" includes espacially all positive ones.

Comment: I answer the second question at the end of my answer, so I actually don't see how one could mistake the yes, to be an answer for the latter question